# Insert to in HIVE

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I,ve a problem with my hive script.

I want to extract two columns from the same tablee with two diferents where clauses into a new table. Im doing the next:

```
create database IF NOT EXISTS basedatos_financiera;
use basedatos_financiera;
create table IF NOT EXISTS nasdaq (fecha string,open float,high float,low float,close float,volume float,adjclose float) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
load data local inpath '/home/Documents/Data/nasdaq.csv' overwrite into table nasdaq;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS aux_nasdaq;

create table IF NOT EXISTS aux_nasdaq (dif float,predic float);


insert into aux_nasdaq (dif) select open from nasdaq where nasdaq.fecha >= '1971-02-08' and  nasdaq.fecha <='2016-04-01'; 

insert into aux_nasdaq (predic) select close from nasdaq where nasdaq.fecha >= '1971-02-05' and  nasdaq.fecha <='2016-03-31';
```

Doing these the new table aux_nasdaq generate two columns like i want, but with the problem of null fields,something like that:

[Example of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eDaC.png)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
insert into aux_nasdaq (dif, predic)
SELECT
    CASE
            WHEN nasdaq.fecha >= '1971-02-08' and  nasdaq.fecha <='2016-04-01'
                THEN open
            ELSE NULL
            END AS dif
    CASE
            WHEN nasdaq.fecha >= '1971-02-05' and  nasdaq.fecha <='2016-03-31'
                THEN close
            ELSE NULL
            END AS predic
FROM nasdaq
```

first try select query, fetching data properly or not then use insert. let me know if not work

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the answer, i try yours but send me the following error: http://imgur.com/g8Ii0QR

Comment: try the updated query. Actually I was giving the count that why error occurred.